# Socket exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, asyncsocket, serversocket

Recently, in my school has project about http proxy class. So it's purpose is when you type url on browser, the request come to your proxy, after extract the host, you recreate a new request and request to destination server, and then, you will receive data from destination server and send back to browser to render a page.

I create a asynchronous http proxy server class. In StateObject class, I have two socket, one is workSocket to handle a new request from browser and second is destinationSocket to handle a destination socket.

Before send new request from browser to destination server, I store destinationSocket and handler socket to StateObject object. By doing that, in AsynCallBack ReceiveFromDestinationServer function, I can retrieve destinationSocket to receive data from destination server and workSocket to send the data received back to browser. And BeginReceive run again until the data received is over.

I get this exception in Send method in Socket in callback ReceiveFromDestinationServer method.

Please help me fix it. Thanks for reading.

This is my code:

```
public class ServerListerner
{
    private const int TCPPort = 80;
    private const string EOF = "\r\n";        
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.                    
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }       
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();
        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        // And begin receive data from client
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;        
        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        if (bytesRead > 0) {            
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer));

            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if(content != "")
            {
                // All the data has been read from the client. 
                // Change data to string array to easy access.
                string[] requestLines = Regex.Split(content, EOF);
                // Get remote host
                string remoteHost = requestLines[0].Split(' ')[1].Replace("http://", "").Split('/')[0];

                // Create a destination socket and connect to remote host at TCP port
                Socket destinationSocket= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                destinationSocket.Connect(remoteHost, TCPPort);
                // Send the data to destination socket.
                state.workSocket = handler;
                state.destinationSocket = destinationSocket;
                destinationSocket.Send(state.buffer);
                destinationSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFromDestinationServer), state);
            } else {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveFromDestinationServer(IAsyncResult ar)
    {                        
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket destinationSocket = state.destinationServer;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = destinationSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {                    
                client.Send(state.buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);                    
                destinationSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFromDestinationServer), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // Exception here
                destinationSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);                
                destinationSocket.Close();
                client.Close();
            }             


    }
}
```

**Update**: ReceiveFromDestinationServer function
I added Thread.Sleep(10) after bytesRead. I think sleep is important, when set is 10, some sites load quickly, some sites load just some information, when set is 100, after load sites, the application is exit automatically. **But the exception is still exists.**

Answer (score 0):

It could be the remote host is not running or not listening to the port your are trying to connect. You may need to check state of the server application using telnet

```
 telnet ipaddr port
```

Comment: I get 400 Bad Request on cmd, but I can read data which are received from destination server, it like enscript or encode with ???@s?, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is for interacting between client and your server. the 'handler' in 'AcceptCallback' is socket for sending bytes back to the browser instead of sending to destination.
So you need to write another working pair(async)/one(sync) socket(s) to achieve a http proxy. First your should make clear what's the request and response look like.
Browser firstly send to you:

```
browserIP ===> proxyIP
GET domainname.com
....
```

and then proxy do the relying:

```
proxyIP ===> domainname.com'sIP
GET domain name
....
```

after your proxy got the response from domainname.com, send it back to browserIP. That's what you do, and in .NET you also need to handle some proxy-specific http headers, like X-forwarded-by. etc.

but in portion your code:
Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);//This line create a new socket only to send bytes back to the browser: so your browser will got a reply the same as its request.

```
    // Create the state object.  
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
```

so you need to create another new Socket and a new pairs of handlers.To really send the request to destination. And before you create them. You need to fetch the real IP address for the destination (your proxy don't know and your client don't know IP address of the destination[domainname.com] )

### Change these two and see if it works:

1. you have two sockets destinationServer and destinationSocket in your StateObject??? and It seems destinationServer is always null, so in ReceiveFromDestinationServer:line2 you should use **state.destinationSocket** instead;
2. in ReadCallback:line29 you should use **destinationSocket.Send(state.buffer,bytesRead,SocketFlags.None);** instead, or you will send the whole buffer to destination, then surely you will get a '400 bad request'

Comment: In Sytem.NET, my teacher is allow me to use only class Socket. I test AcceptCallback function, it's just accept a new connection and begin receive data from browser, in ReadCallBack, I can read totally http headers. So I think it's not a problem. I do it exactly as your illustration

Comment: Yes, it create a new request socket and start to connect together. I can receive data from destination server, but when I send back to browser I get exception in send method.

Comment: sorry, have your tried to wrap up all code in ReceiveFromDestinationServer in a lock(){} to prevent thread confliction?

Comment: should be like private void ReceiveFromDestinationServer(IAsyncResult ar)
{lock(this.aLockerObject){   ......all your code...}}

Comment: on EndAccept, the document is say: "Asynchronously accepts an incoming connection attempt and creates a new System.Net.Sockets.Socket to handle remote host communication.". So the handler socket like a bridge to communicate between my proxy and browser. 
Oh, I know what your mean, I created a new socket to send request to destination. You can meet it in below in my code in question.

Comment: I lock the client socket, but it's still has exception

Comment: locking it can prevent mutiple runing thread of ReceiveFromDestinationServer accessing the buffer at the same time. does it work?

Comment: can you edit your question, to update the code, then I can see whether the usage of lock is right.

Comment: I just update my code. I don't know lock client is right? I so confuse

Comment: try using client.Send(state.buffer,bytesRead,SocketFlags.None); instead in ReceiveFromDestinationServer see if any change occurs

Comment: I just update code again, I remove lock and replace with your send methods, some site is quick, some site is down, and some sites is slow, but exception is still exists. I think the socket close is not right.

Comment: sorry, I went sleep last night, cause its too late, I debuged your code locally can corrected some mistakes and it works, see my modified answer.

Comment: I changed my code in yesterday and update question, it work. But sometimes, application is automatically exists. I try catch and debug, but have something wrong in function, and I can't figure out